# How do I return a vector<T> from a function in c++

Tags: c++, generics, vector

I am creating a generic data structure and I want to return a vector that contains some of the objects in my structure.

I tried

```
template<class T>
vector<T> DataStructure<T>::getItems(int count)
{
    vector<T> items;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        items.push_back(data[i]);      
    return items;
}
```

But the compiler says

error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type

error: expected ';' before '<' token

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vector` is not defined.

You need to `#include <vector>` and to specify its namespace either using `std::vector` or putting an `using namespace std;` in your function or at the global scope (this latter suggestion should be avoided).

---

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
std::vector<T> DataStructure<T>::getItems(int count)
{
    std::vector<T> items;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        items.push_back(data[i]);      
    return items;
}
```

Comment: do not, ever, recommend the `using namespace` directive please, it brings more woes than it's worth :/

Comment: @Matthieu M: I didn't recommend it, just said it was a possible solution. I think we should talk about the `using` directive (and say why it should be avoided!) instead of _hiding_ it, otherwise when the people we're talking to will encounter it they won't know what it is and will likely misuse it.

Answer (score 4):

It's `std::vector`, not just `vector`. Other than that,`data` is undefined in the snippet. But in general, this is the way to return a vector.

Answer (score 2):

As an complement to @etarion perfect answer, the most idiomatic way to perform your operation is, assuming `data` is of type `T*`:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> DataStructure<T>::getItems(int count)
{
    return std::vector<T>(data, data + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since getItems' definition must be available through the header anyway, as it is a method of a class template, it is easiest to define it within the class definition:

```
template<class T>
struct DataStructure {
  std::vector<T> getItems(int count) const {
    assert(0 <= count && count <= data.size());  // don't forget to check count

    // if you must use op[] with data:
    // std::vector<T> items;
    // for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    //   items.push_back(data[i]);      
    // return items;

    // if data is a container (using random-access iterators here):
    return std::vector<T>(data.begin(), data.begin() + count);

    // if data is an array:
    // return std::vector<T>(data, data + count);
  }

  std::vector<T> data;  // or is data something else?
};
```